# Update data without modifying old data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I was wondering how I would be able to update a table of mine without modifying the data. I have an application which allows users to enter data, but if they make a mistake they can modify the data entered. But when the user modifies the data it overwrites the data previously entered.

Is there a way of keeping the old data but if the user does modify the data it will show on another added column which may say, "data modified".

This is what I have taken from my application in the regional source

```
select "PROBLEM_ID", 
"PROBLEM_TYPE_ID",
"DATE_REPORTED",
"DESCRIPTION",
"POSTCODE"
from "#OWNER#"."CS_PROBLEMS"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a "post update for each row" trigger to save the old date in a history table. Or a "pre update for each row" trigger to set extra columns in the existing table. Then you can create a screen or procedure to retrieve the historical data. Or restore with a manual process.